# Netsuite Saved Search Line fields

Tags: netsuite

I´m trying to make a saved search  and show  items  that aren´t closed in a saleOrder
[image]

But  I can´t find this field in the list in criteria or result tab.
I don´t know if there is a "Transaction Lines" in  saved search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a saved search, it should be the field `Closed`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!,  I saw this "Closed"  but I was thinking is related to the saleOrder document, so is MainLine is false aim to the lines right?

Comment: Closed only applies to line items, not the transaction as a whole.  If all of the lines are closed, then the document itself is closed.  Clicking the close button on an order is just a shortcut to checking the closed box on each line.  The mainline false isn't really required to use the closed filter.

Comment: I've tried this with the mainline true, and it didn't work; It checks the order itself then and not the line items. Keep mainline to false and group your results.